# How chaotic is the double-pendulum if the arms are not perfectly rigid?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, non-linear-systems, chaos-theory

The double pendulum is a famous example of a chaotic system. It consists of one pendulum hanging from the end of another pendulum, which in turn hangs from a fixed point. In the traditional version, both arms are perfectly rigid.

Here's an easy way to generalize the model so that the arms are not perfectly rigid. Let $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ be the variable locations of the ends of the two arms, where masses $m_x$ and $m_y$ are located. (The arms themselves are massless.) Take the system's equations of motion to be
\begin{align}
\newcommand{\bfx}{\mathbf{x}}
\newcommand{\bfy}{\mathbf{y}}
\newcommand{\bfg}{\mathbf{g}}
 m_x\ddot\bfx
  + \nabla_\bfx V(\bfx,\bfy) &= 0
\\
 m_y\ddot\bfy
  + \nabla_\bfy V(\bfx,\bfy) &= 0
\end{align}
with potential energy
\begin{align}
 V(\bfx,\bfy) 
 = 
  &- m_x\bfg\cdot\bfx  + f\big(k_x,L_x,|\bfx|\big)
\\
 &-  m_y\bfg\cdot\bfy + f\big(k_y,L_y,|\bfy-\bfx|\big) 
\end{align}
where $\bfg$ is the acceleration of gravity (a downward-pointing vector) and the function $f$ is defined by
$$
 f(k.L,x) = k(L^2-x^2)^2.
$$
The $L$s are the nominal arm-lengths, and the $k$s are the degree of rigidity of the arms. For finite $k$s, the potential energy $V$ is a smooth function of $\bfx$ and $\bfy$. The perfectly rigid version corresponds to $k_x,k_y\to\infty$: in that limit, any deviation from the nominal lengths $L_x,L_y$ costs infinite energy.

How chaotic is the system with finite-but-large values of $k_x$ and $k_y$, if chaos is quantified in the standard way(s)? Intuitively, the closer $k_x,k_y$ are to zero, the less chaotic the system should be, because taking the limit $k_x,k_y\to 0$ gives a pair of freely-falling masses that don't interact with each other at all. But can we determine how the degree of chaos (quantified in a standard way) scales with $k_x,k_y$, at least roughly?

Comment: Would a better way to model the flexibility of the arms be by treating them as springs? Or do you have this particular description in mind for a reason?

Comment: Well, we can simulate your equations, compute some measure of chaos (e.g., the Lyapunov exponent) for these simulations, average over an appropriate ensemble of  initial conditions and plot the dependency on your parameters. If you know the right tools, it’s mostly legwork. But something tells me that this doesn’t satisfy you. What exactly do you want to do with this information?

Comment: @fewfew4 My intent was to model them as something like springs, but with a potential-energy function that is a polynomial function of the coordinates. If using some other continuous function like $f(k,L,x)=k(L-|\mathbf{x}|)^2$ makes the math easier, despite not being differentiable everywhere, then that would be fine.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I'm mostly interested in building intuition. Knowing the results from computer simulations can contribute to intuition, but I was hoping for some kind of analytic/intuitive argument. The reasoning (if sound) is more important to me than the results.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Standard double pendulum model not depends  on $k_x, k_y$, but it depends on $L_x, L_y$.  Can you formulate your model so that it has standard model as a limit at large $k_x, k_y$?

Comment: @AlexTrounev If we consider the set of all solutions with energy $\leq E$ for some fixed $E$, then the limit of arbitrarily large $k_x$ and $k_y$ restricts $|\mathbf{x}|$ and $|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|$ to arbitrarily small neighborhoods of $L_x$ and $L_y$. That's why I wrote "The perfectly rigid version [which is the standard model] corresponds to $k_x,k_y\to\infty$."

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Ok, may be it is correct about limit, but what kind of elastic deformation is described by this model?

Comment: @AlexTrounev It's not meant to be an accurate model of any realistic kind of elastic deformation. My criteria for choosing the model were: (1) the equations of motion should have the simple Newtonian form $m \ddot x+\nabla V=0$  with a smooth potential $V$ and no constraints, and (2) it should have the standard model as a limiting case.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Please pay attention, that bending modes of cantilever beam vibration  can be  chaotic at high amplitude. In your model one arm with parameters $L_x, k_x$, for instance, is cantilever beam as well. So, at small $k_x$ we have nonlinear high amplitude chaotic vibration of arm, and not linear oscillation as in your model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that $k_{x,y}\to 0$ will be non chaotic, but, before this limit, the extra degrees of freedom of flexible arms should allow for more complex motion. At any rate I don't expect the degree of chaos to change too smoothly or monotonically with $k_{x,y}$, but rather that, e.g., periodic windows from resonances between spring and pendulum movements show up at intermediate values (resonances in the simple spring-pendulum have been studied for some time, see, e.g., [here](https://doi.org/10.1088/0951-7715/11/6/009) and [here](https://doi.org/10.1137/S0036139900365323)).

As Wrzlprmft comments, some simulations should help with building an intuition — it sounds like a nice undergrad project — if you do perform some, please share here your results. **Edit**: There are already a number of numerical implementations and simulation results available, for instance: in [java](https://www.compadre.org/osp/items/detail.cfm?ID=12581) (Open Source Physics), [Matlab (1)](https://www.math.arizona.edu/%7Egabitov/teaching/141/math_485/Midterm_Presentations/Elastic_Pedulum.pdf), [Matlab (2)](https://mse.redwoods.edu/darnold/math55/DEProj/sp04/jordan/presentation.pdf), [Mathematica (1)](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/DoubleSpringPendulum/), [Mathematica (2)](https://www.physicsandstuffiguess.com/pendulums/elasticDoublePendulum.html), [Maple](https://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=5082&view=html), etc.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Can you explain the reason for your expectation that "periodic windows from resonances between spring and pendulum movements show up at intermediate values"? Is it based on experience with another model, or on a property of the usual rigid double-pendulum?

Comment: (I could do some simulations, but my time is focused on other subjects, so I was hoping to learn from research that others have already done on this particular topic. Not enough time to specialize in everything.)

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly I expect resonances mostly because they are generically present in such systems, but I added a reference (and other bits) to the answer. It might also be worthy it to remember that, while there is often chaos associated with these resonances, it might be restricted to a very small region of the phase space, see, e.g., https://webspace.science.uu.nl/~verhu101/SAMOSpap.pdf .